# Dictionary inside IDictionary MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, razor

I had to alter a radio button to include a new value.
To do this I had to put a Dictionary inside an IDictionary.  The key pulls in great for the IDictionary but the Dictionary int and string don't pull in at all.
I believe it's my front end code. 
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and provide an example on how to fix?

**Action Parameter in Controller**

```
IDictionary<String, Dictionary<int, String>>
```

**View**

```
<fieldset>
<legend class="sr-only">Actions</legend>
<input type="hidden" name="customerId" value="@account.CustomerId" />
<input type="hidden" name="yearSetupId" value="@account.YearId" />
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="accountActions[@(account.CustomerId)].Key[@(account.Id)].Value" value="" checked="checked">Do nothing</label>
@{
     var possibleActions = account.Balance < 0 ? new[] { 
     BalanceAdjustmentType.Zeroed, BalanceAdjustmentType.Issued }
                                    : new[] { BalanceAdjustmentType.Under, BalanceAdjustmentType.Sent };
                                }
@foreach (var action in possibleActions)
                                {
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="accountActions[@(account.CustomerId)].Key[@(account.YearId)].Value" value="@action.BalanceId">@action.Text</label>
                                }
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your controller parameter means actually.
But I supposed the "accountActions" in your view was the variable of your "controller parameter".
If so, then your could access the nested dict value by accountActions[Key][InnerKey].

```
<fieldset>
    <legend class="sr-only">Actions</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="customerId" value="@account.CustomerId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="yearSetupId" value="@account.YearId" />
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="@accountActions[account.CustomerId][account.Id]" value="" checked="checked">
        Do nothing
    </label>    

    @{ 
        var possibleActions = account.Balance < 0 
        ? new[] { BalanceAdjustmentType.Zeroed, BalanceAdjustmentType.Issued } 
        : new[] { BalanceAdjustmentType.Under, BalanceAdjustmentType.Sent }; 
    } 

    @foreach (var action in possibleActions) { 
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="@accountActions[account.CustomerId][account.YearId]" value="@action.BalanceId">
            @action.Text
        </label>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I use the above, the result that is passed into my controller is the CustomerId as the key then the value has a count of 0 so it isn't seeing the YearId or the BalanceId for the nested values.

Comment: I think you need to think about the inner key is AccountId or YearId. I don't believe these two could be contained in the same dict. Please check the line:6 and the foeach loop from above code snippet.